# Obtaining an access token via cURL

Tags: curl, keycloak

Simple question:

Why does the following code work... (it returns the access token just fine)

```
curl --data "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=synchronization_tool&client_secret=8f6a6e73-66ca-4f8f-1234-ab909147f1cf" http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

And this one doesn't?

```
curl -d  '{"grant_type":"client_credentials","client_secret":"8f6a6e73-66ca-4f8f-1234-ab909147f1cf","client_id":"synchronization_tool"}' http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

It gives gives me:

```
"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing form parameter: grant_type"}
```

**Aren't they supposed to be two completely analogous requests?**

Comment: Is that a typo in your second request? It's missing a quote at the start of the json. I'm getting 404 with both those requests.

Comment: @delephin thanks for pointing it out. Unfortunately it was a typo :( About the 404, I guess it normal since https://keycloak-server.company.com is not a real server name. I'll edit the question to avoid confusion. Thanks!!!

Comment: Did the second req work after you made the change? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Expand `this one doesn't`.. Do you get any error?

Comment: @delephin nope, it was just a typo when I copied and pasted from my terminal to SO

Comment: @extreme-biker. Yes. I'll edit the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
curl -d 'client_id=xxx' -d 'username=xxx' -d 'password=xxx' -d 'grant_type=password' \
    'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/YOUR_REALM_NAME/protocol/openid-connect/token' | \
    python -m json.tool
```

This works for me, and it will give you the `access_token` and `session_token`

Comment: you may also need `-d 'client_secret=your_client_secret'`

Comment: @AlexBurdusel, in 2023 the client_secret parameter is definitely needed, and without it the error message isn't so clear: `{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Invalid client or Invalid client credentials"}`.

Comment: @AlexBurdusel: the `client_secret` is only required for `grant_type=client_credentials`. It's not needed if you're supplying a password, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 12):

## Curl Command:

```bash
curl \
  -d "client_id=account" \
  -d "client_secret=YOUR_SECRET" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
  "http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

## Response:

```json
{
  "access_token": "...redacted...",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_expires_in": 0,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "not-before-policy": 0,
  "scope": "profile email"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Heads up when using Keycloak 17.0+. You have to omit `/auth` in the endpoint because the API has changed. Therfore, you need to execute following command:

```
curl -d 'client_id=xxx' -d 'username=xxx' -d 'password=xxx' -d 'grant_type=password' \ 
  'http://localhost:8080/realms/YOUR_REALM_NAME/protocol/openid-connect/token'
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71634718/9199819) for the original question/answer.

Comment: ++, I just spend few hours to troubleshoot this. Error if you still have auth in the url `"error": "Unable to find matching target resource method"`

Answer (score 7):

Alright, it seems those cURL queries ARE NOT ANALOGOUS.

Also, the endpoint http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token does not understand JSON and it only accepts x-www-form-urlencoded queries.

Answer (score 3):

```
curl 'https://example.com/auth/realms/realm-test1/protocol/openid-connect/token'  \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=realm-test1' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=username@example.com' \
--data-urlencode 'password=pass123xvDD##xds2'
```

If the password contained special bash characters like &,%,etc, then curl command  failed

Comment: My setup have worked without "auth" after domain. i.e.: https://example.com/realms/realm-test1/protocol/openid-connect/token (all other, just fine)