# Keycloak: Could not find resource for full path

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am trying to get the REST API of keycloak to work.

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283281/how-to-activate-the-rest-api-of-keycloak#) I was able to get the token. But when trying the example for the list of users in the first answer, I get the error:

```
"error": "RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://PATHTOCEAKLOAK:81/auth/user/realms/master/users"
```

Here my request with Postman:

[image]

As I am using a Bitnami-container the admin is called user that's why I am using */auth/user/* instead of */auth/admin*/

Comment: Is the "serviceAccountsEnabled" activated on your client ?

Comment: Also make sure your "user" has sufficient privilege to manage realm users.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the access type for "admin-cli" to confidential and was now able to activate the option "SeviceAccountsEnabled". In Role Mapping for "user" it already had admin, just to try I added the other available roles (create-realm, uma_authorization, offline_access) but I still get the same error. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

For those who are still facing this error and using 17.0+ version of Keycloak, there's a change in endpoints as per the [official documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource). I resolved this issue by just using `{realm}/user` and omitting `/auth` in between.

Comment: do you know how to make keycloak to respond to /auth/* path anyway? I'm forced to have this path for backward compartibility

Comment: @Kostanos set `KC_HTTP_RELAITVE_PATH=/auth` to have it behave the same way it did on the old wildfly distribution. While switching from wildfly to quarkus, we decided to not use the old "auth" basepath, but use "/" instead, as it is more clean, and allow to use "/<path>" optionally to keep it backwards compatible. See e.g. https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config?q=relative - you have to run a build for this to take effect, so either use an optimized docker image (see container guide) or use the `--auto-build` flag. Or, when onprem/not containerized, run a `build` command first with the cmd.

Comment: Hi thanks @Akansha_p but how the resulting path will appear then? in this case?

Comment: @buddhiv, as per the question, flololan is trying to get list of all users. And based on the documentation, we need to use ```GET /{realm}/users``` as the endpoint, So, the url should look like ```http://PATHTOCEAKLOAK:81/{your_realm_name}/users```

Comment: thanks. but the working path for me was `http://{domain}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo`. :)

Comment: Great answer, very annoying implementation. As a reference, I had the following entry in the openid-configuration: "jwks_uri":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/certs" ---- auth had to be omitted here too ---- http://localhost:8080/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/certs

Answer (score 15):

In addition to [@Akanksha_p's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71634718/17242583), here is a command to get the token using `curl`:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "client_id=your-client" -d "username=some-user" -d "password=hardpassword" -d "grant_type=password" -X POST https://your.fqdn.server:8443/realms/yourrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know wich url are available on your current realm you can go in Realm -> Settings and click on "Ednpoints" link.

Or directly go to the following url : http://{host}:{port}/realms/{your_realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Latest for image `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1.1`

```
$docker exec -it container_name bash
```

Now from the container shell (bash)

```
bash-5.1$ cd ~/bin/ 
bash-5.1$./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080 --realm master --user admin
```

Enter your credentials for the admin user

```
bash-5.1$./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE --server http://localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

I was actually working on the same and using docker image of bitnami/keycloak:latest

it worked with just removing /auth from base path and keeping it as /admin

something like this (GET http://localhost:8085/admin/realms/test-realm/users)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCScY.png)